# How to set a BCE year using GregorianCalendar

Tags: java, date, gregorian-calendar

I have an assignment that converts dates from one calendar system to another.

The documentation for GregorianCalendar seems to suggest that you **can** use dates with BCE years, but I have no idea how.  If I simply make the year negative, i.e.

```
 GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(-20, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0);
 System.out.println(cal.getTime.toString());
```

It prints out 'Sun Feb 02 03:00:00 GMT-05:00 21', which is clearly not correct.

Comment: @hollaburoo - what would be correct for your usage?  Bear in mind that the era (BC or AD) doesn't (normally) appear in the default date-time format, and that there is no year zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the ERA to BC (BC is a static field on [GregorianCalendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html)).

> The standard (Gregorian) calendar has 2 eras, BC and AD.

[http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html)

e.g.

```
calendar.set(Calendar.ERA, GregorianCalendar.BC);
```